# AngualrJS: How to I pass the data to bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-strap

Here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/iwvjJcUurUW2AvkDArfz?p=preview

I am using Modal from http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

I want to pass the transaction-id to delete function, how is this achievable using AngularJS?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the ng-click of the modal's delete button:

```
ng-click="modal.saved=true;delete(transaction.id);hide()"
```

Delete function:

```
 $scope.delete = function(id) {
   alert(id);
  }
```

Working plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/lzKAjCyIySoz45r56YjL?p=preview

I believe the strap inherits the current scope so you just pass in the transaction id (or you could pass in the entire transaction object) to the delete function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read about the scope, but I was trying wrong syntax `delete({{transaction.id}})` instead of `delete(transation.id)`